# How to resolve 'ClassNotFoundException' error in Selenium?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, exception

Error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
```

Eclipse Error:

[image]

While executing my code, getting above error, can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: Does your path point to the correct location for the Selenium classes?

Comment: Please copy-paste the text of the error message, not a screenshot with it!

Comment: I have the same problem but I am not using maven dependencies. How do I solve my error because I am quite new to this platform

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue. I've added guava JRE.jar in project

You can refer here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/23.6-jre to add maven dependency

OR

Download guava_jre.jar file from http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/23.6-jre/ and add it in your project

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from the error stacktrace it is caused by the `com.google.common.base.Function` it means either the jar file is missing or it is not loaded properly. You can try the following.

**1.**
If you are using maven for dependency management I would suggest.
Go to the following path *C:\users\your_user_id\.m2\repository* locate your jar file for which you are getting the error(in your case com/google/commons) delete that folder and rebuild the project and update the maven.

**2.**
If you have added Jar files directly by using configure build path options and remove the dependency and add it again.

Answer (score -2):

You are trying to create a `WebDriver` instance with `ChromeDriver` constructor. This is not correct. Change `WebDriver` in your code to `ChromeDriver`.

Comment: This is incorrect. ``ChromeDriver`` implements ``WebDriver``, so creating a ``WebDriver`` instance with ``new ChromeDriver()`` is perfectly valid. (It is odd that the class name is Firefoxbrowser, though…)